# IndexError: list index out of range - python error

Tags: python, list

I have a huge list of lists(there are 518 lists with each one of them having different amount of sublists, but i cannot upload all of it because i exceed word limit so hopefully it can work even with this sample)

```
fall_3_list = [[['CS322', 'CS312', 'CS300', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS300', 'CS312', 'CS322', 'GER']], [['', '', 'CS300', 'FREE', 'CS312'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS300', '', 'CS312'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS300', '', 'CS312']], [['CS322', 'GER', 'GER', 'CS321', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'GER', 'CS312'], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'CS322', 'GER', 'STAT205'], ['GER', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS322', 'STAT205'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'CS306', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS306', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE', 'FREE'], ['CS306', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE', 'FREE'], ['CS306', 'GER', 'FREE', 'CS310', 'GER'], ['CS310', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS310', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS306', 'GER', 'CS310', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS306', 'GER', 'CS310', 'FREE']], [['CS321', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'GER', 'CS325']], [['CS310', 'CS300', 'CS450', 'CS312', 'FREE']], [['CS310', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER', ''], ['CS310', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER', '']], [['CS322', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'STAT205', 'CS322'], ['CS300', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'FREE'], ['CS300', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'FREE'], ['CS306', 'CS300', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'FREE'], ['CS306', 'CS300', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'FREE', 'STAT205'], ['CS322', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'STAT205']], [['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS312', '', 'CS325']], [['CS206', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'FREE', 'CS325']], [['FREE', 'FREE', 'GER', '', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'GER'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'GER'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'GER'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'GER'], ['', 'FREE', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['', 'FREE', '', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['', 'FREE', '', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS321']], [['MATH220', 'CS450', 'CS300', 'FREE', 'FREE']], [['FREE', 'CS312', 'MATH220', 'CS310', ''], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'MATH220', 'CS310', ''], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'MATH220', 'CS310', ''], ['MATH220', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', '']], [['', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'CS322', ''], ['', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'CS322', ''], ['', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321']], [['CS450', '', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS321']], [['CS306', 'CS321', 'STAT205', 'CS310', '']], [['', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS306', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS322', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE']], [['FREE', 'FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS312'], ['FREE', 'FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS312']], [['FREE', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS325', 'STAT205'], ['FREE', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS325', 'STAT205']], [['CS306', 'MATH220', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'GER']], [['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321'], ['GER', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'CS322'], ['GER', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['GER', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['GER', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['GER', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'CS322'], ['GER', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'CS322'], ['CS300', 'CS306', 'GER', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'CS321', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'CS321', 'GER']], [['FREE', 'CS300', 'CS306', 'GER', ''], ['FREE', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', '']], [['CS310', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'CS322', 'CS312'], ['CS300', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'CS310', 'CS312']], [['FREE', 'CS322', 'STAT205', 'CS310', 'FREE'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'STAT205', 'CS310', 'FREE']], [['CS450', 'CS300', 'STAT205', 'CS310', 'GER']], [['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS450', 'CS321', 'CS325'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS450', 'CS321', 'CS325'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS450', 'CS321', 'CS325']], [['CS300', 'CS310', 'GER', 'STAT205', 'MAJOR']], [['FREE', 'FREE', 'FREE', '', 'GER'], ['', '', '', 'FREE', 'GER']], [['FREE', 'CS206', '', 'GER', 'CS321']], [['CS312', 'GER', 'STAT205', 'CS325', ''], ['', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS325', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'ENG204', 'GER']], [['CS450', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'CS310', 'FREE']], [['CS322', 'FREE', 'MATH220', 'CS321', 'CS325']], [['CS206', 'CS312', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'FREE']], [['MATH220', 'CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS321']], [['FREE', 'GER', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS325'], ['FREE', 'GER', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS325'], ['FREE', 'GER', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS325'], ['FREE', 'FREE', 'GER', 'GER', 'CS325']], [['STAT205', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'GER'], ['STAT205', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'GER'], ['STAT205', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'GER'], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'STAT205', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'FREE', 'STAT205', 'CS310', 'GER']], [['CS322', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'CS300', 'GER']], [['CS450', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'STAT205', 'GER']], [['CS450', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS322', 'CS306']], [['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS310', 'CS322', 'GER', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE']], [['CS450', 'CS300', 'GER', 'CS310', 'FREE']], [['CS310', 'CS306', 'CS450', 'ENG204', 'CS312'], ['CS310', 'CS450', 'CS306', 'ENG204', 'CS312']], [['CS206', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'CS306', 'FREE']], [['CS306', 'CS450', 'CS312', 'GER', '']], [['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS300', 'CS321', '']], [['FREE', 'CS450', '', 'CS321', 'STAT205']], [['', 'FREE', '', 'CS321', 'STAT205'], ['', 'FREE', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'STAT205'], ['FREE', 'FREE', '', 'CS321', 'STAT205']], [['', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'CS322', ''], ['', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'CS322', ''], ['', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['FREE', '', 'FREE', 'CS322', 'CS321']], [['MATH220', 'FREE', 'CS306', 'CS325', 'FREE'], ['MATH220', 'FREE', 'CS306', 'CS325', 'FREE']], [['STAT205', 'CS322', 'MATH220', 'GER', 'FREE']], [['FREE', 'GER', 'CS310', 'CS312', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS310', 'GER', 'CS312', 'GER'], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'CS310', 'FREE', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE', 'GER'], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS310', 'FREE'], ['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS310', 'CS312', 'FREE', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS310', 'CS312', 'FREE', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['CS310', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'GER'], ['CS312', 'FREE', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'CS310', 'GER', 'FREE']], [['', '', 'FREE', 'CS321', 'CS312'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS321', 'FREE'], ['FREE', 'CS312', '', 'CS321', ''], ['FREE', 'FREE', 'CS312', '', 'CS321']], [['CS310', 'FREE', 'STAT205', 'GER', '']], [['CS300', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'GER', 'STAT205'], ['CS300', 'CS306', 'GER', 'FREE', 'STAT205'], ['CS306', 'CS300', 'GER', 'FREE', 'STAT205']], [['CS312', 'ENG204', 'CS450', 'CS310', 'FREE']], [['FREE', 'CS300', '', 'CS321', 'STAT205'], ['FREE', 'CS300', '', 'CS321', 'STAT205']], [['FREE', 'MATH220', 'CS306', 'GER', ''], ['CS306', '', 'FREE', 'MATH220', 'GER']], [['FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS325', 'STAT205'], ['FREE', 'STAT205', 'CS325', 'GER', 'CS312']], [['CS322', 'CS306', 'CS450', '', 'CS321']], [['CS312', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS322', ''], ['FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS322', ''], ['CS312', 'CS322', 'GER', 'FREE', ''], ['CS312', 'CS322', 'GER', 'FREE', ''], ['CS312', 'CS322', 'GER', 'FREE', ''], ['FREE', 'CS322', 'GER', 'CS312', ''], ['FREE', '', 'CS322', 'GER', 'CS312'], ['GER', 'CS312', '', 'CS322', 'FREE'], ['GER', 'CS312', '', 'CS322', 'FREE'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS322'], ['CS322', '', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS312'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'GER', 'CS322'], ['FREE', '', 'CS312', 'CS322', 'GER'], ['CS322', '', 'FREE', 'GER', 'CS312'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS312', 'CS322', 'GER'], ['GER', 'CS312', '', 'FREE', 'CS322'], ['GER', 'CS312', '', 'FREE', 'CS322']], [['CS306', 'FREE', '', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['CS306', 'FREE', '', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['CS306', 'FREE', '', 'CS321', 'CS322'], ['CS322', '', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'CS321'], ['CS322', '', 'CS306', 'FREE', 'CS321'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS306', 'CS322', 'CS321'], ['', 'FREE', 'CS306', 'CS321', 'CS322'], ['CS322', 'FREE', 'CS306', '', 'CS321']]]
```

and what I want to do is take the first sublist of each listlike this:

```
combination_fall_3 = [item[0] for item in fall_3_list]
```

but I keep getting the same error:

> combination_fall_3 = [item[0] for item in fall_3_list] IndexError:
>   list index out of range

But for the rest of the lists that I have, I have 15 lists that look like fall_3_list, this doesn't happen. Of course, they all have different length, not 518 as this one but I use exact same code. I cannot understand why I get this error since I do not define the length of combination_fall_3 before(in case it was an error because I gave it smaller length) and I am just asking for first sublist of each list to be added.

Comment: One of the elements of `fall_3_list` must be empty.

Comment: you mean empty string or empty sublist? @DanielWalker

Comment: Empty meaning *with no elements inside*, much like `[]`. In that case, the `item[0]` access attempt would fail.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is because some of your lists will have no items in it and `item[0]` will not exist.

To diagnose these kind of errors you have to look at which *indices* you use. On the line that throws the error you only try to "index" (grab an element of) 1 list: `item[0]`. If the error then reports that the "list index is out of range" it means that element 0 in that list does not exist.

You can fix this for example like this:

```
combination_fall_3 = [item[0] for item in fall_3_list if item]
```

Where the sublist `item` only evaluates to `False` if it is empty.